# how can i put these inputs into a function without declaring different variables

Tags: python

I need to optimize my code, but I don't know how to go about that. I can make `fahr_inputs` all into one function, but I can't get it to work

```
# fahr to cel conversion
def toCelsius (fahr):
    cel = (fahr - 32) * 5/9
    return float(cel)

#dispaly the input and average of fahrenheit and celsius
def displayFahr():
    sum = fahr_input1 + fahr_input2 + fahr_input3 + fahr_input4 + fahr_input5
    average = sum / 5
    print ("Your fahrenheit numbers were: ",fahr_input1, fahr_input2, fahr_input3, fahr_input4, fahr_input5)
    print ("The sum of fahrinheit is : ", sum)
    print ("the average is: ", average)

fahr_input1 = int(input("Please enter a Fahrenheit temperature here: "))
fahr_input2 = int(input("Please enter a Fahrenheit temperature here: "))
fahr_input3 = int(input("Please enter a Fahrenheit temperature here: "))
fahr_input4 = int(input("Please enter a Fahrenheit temperature here: "))
fahr_input5 = int(input("Please enter a Fahrenheit temperature here: "))

displayFahr()
```

I'm trying this, but its not working.

```
def fahr_input ():
    i = 0
    while i < 5:
        input1 = int(input("Please enter a Fahrenheit temperature here: "))
        i + 1
    return input1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# fahr to cel conversion
def toCelsius (fahr):
    cel = (fahr - 32) * 5/9
    return float(cel)

#dispaly the input and average of fahrenheit and celsius
def displayFahr():
    average = sum(inputLs) / len(inputLs)
    print ("Your fahrenheit numbers were: ", end='')
    for i in inputLs:
        print(i, end=' ')
    print ("\nThe sum of fahrinheit is : ", sum(inputLs))
    print ("the average is: ", average)

def fahr_input ():
    i = 0
    inputLs = []
    while i < 5:
        input1 = int(input("Please enter a Fahrenheit temperature here: "))
        inputLs.append(input1)
        i += 1
    return inputLs
inputLs = fahr_input()
displayFahr()
```

Try this

Comment: @dylanaday glad to help you

Answer (score 0):

#### Put the input in a loop:

- There are other options for getting repeated input (e.g. `while-loop`), but given you want 5 temperatures, a `for-loop` suffices.
- A function should do one thing, so having a separate function to calculate celsius, is perfect.
- Collect `temps` directly inside a `list comprehension`

  - [Python List Comprehension Tutorial](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/python-list-comprehension)

#### Code:

```py
def to_celsius(fahr):
    return float((fahr - 32) * 5/9)

def fahr_input():
    return [int(input('Please enter a Fahrenheit temperature here: ')) for _ in range(5)]

def display_temps():
    temps = fahr_input()
    total = sum(temps)
    average = total / len(temps)

    print('\nYour fahrenheit numbers were', ', '.join(str(x) for x in temps), '°F')
    print(f'The sum of fahrenheit is: {total}°F')
    print(f'the average is: {average:0.0F}°F')
    print(f'You average temp in celsius is: {to_celsius(average):0.02f}°C')
```

#### Output of `disply_fahr()`:

```py
Please enter a Fahrenheit temperature here:  33
Please enter a Fahrenheit temperature here:  44
Please enter a Fahrenheit temperature here:  55
Please enter a Fahrenheit temperature here:  66
Please enter a Fahrenheit temperature here:  77

Your fahrenheit numbers were 33, 44, 55, 66, 77 °F
The sum of fahrenheit is: 275°F
the average is: 55°F
You average temp in celsius is: 12.78°C
```